# Which Linux distro does Citrix prefer?

Tags: linux, xen, citrix

Just wondering what Citrix's preferred Linux distribution is for their XenServer?

And what Linux distribution is the XenServer build on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XenServer is built on CentOS.

Several files in /etc contain CentOS references.

Answer (score 2):

XenServer has VM templates for CentOS, RHEL, Oracle Enterprise Linux, SUSE Linux Enterprise, and Debian Lenny. Other than Debian, there templates for both 32 and 64 bit installs, and several past versions. We use CentOS.